# Downsample Timestamp in milisecond range in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, psql, downsampling

I have a table as below

```
timestamp                    v1    v2    v3
2020/01/01 08:10:20.300      10    20    30
2020/01/01 08:10:20.306      11    21    31
2020/01/01 08:10:20.310      12    22    32
2020/01/01 08:10:20.318      13    23    33
2020/01/01 08:10:20.325      14    24    34
.......................
2020/01/01 08:10:21.100      19    29    39
```

As can be seen that the timestamp does not change uniformly in the millisecond and has a lot of granular data. 
I am interested to condense the table such that, the timestamp and data columns average out for every 100 millisecond ie all the data between 100 millisecond gets averaged out.

I have a solution that seems to be working but the average is over every second and not after every 100 millisecond.

```
SELECT date_trunc('second', timestamp) AS timestamp
      ,avg(v1) AS avg_v1
      ,avg(v2) AS avg_v2
      ,avg(v3) AS avg_v3
FROM   myTable
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Please direct me how to solve this issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Consider casting the `timestamp` column to `timestamp(1)`: this will actually round it to the closest decimal second.

```
SELECT 
    "timestamp"::timestamp(1) AS timestamp,
    avg(v1) AS avg_v1,
    avg(v2) AS avg_v2,
    avg(v3) AS avg_v3
FROM myTable
GROUP BY 1;
```

Note that this *rounds* the timestamp instead of *truncating* it. Typically, `08:10:20.306` would become `08:10:20.3`, while `08:10:20.350` would be turned to `08:10:20.4`. This might, or might not be what you really want.

If you really want to truncate to 10s of seconds, then it is a bit more complicated. One option is to truncate the timestamp to minutes, then extract the second parts (all decimals included), turn it to a number, truncate it to 1 decimal, then add it back:

```
SELECT 
    date_trunc('minute', "timestamp") 
        + interval '1 second' 
        * trunc((extract(seconds from  "timestamp"))::numeric, 1) AS timestamp,
    avg(v1) AS avg_v1,
    avg(v2) AS avg_v2,
    avg(v3) AS avg_v3
FROM myTable
GROUP BY 1;
```

Another option to truncate, as commented by Gordon Linoff, is to offset then round. This is simpler than the above solution, and probably more efficient:

```
SELECT 
    ("timestamp" - interval '50 millisecond')::timestamp(1) AS timestamp,
    avg(v1) AS avg_v1,
    avg(v2) AS avg_v2,
    avg(v3) AS avg_v3
FROM myTable
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: . . If you want to truncate to a tenth of a second (what the OP appears to be looking for), then you can just subtract 50 milliseconds:  `("timestamp" - interval '50 
 millisecond')::timestamp(1)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: ah yes, of course, that's much simpler. Many thanks.